# Is there a library like pymedia, but more updated?

Tags: python

the latest release of pymedia was in 2006, and i want the windows version so the latest version for that is released in 2005. i have python 2.7 and pymedia is compatible with 2.4

I have found and [unofficial version](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pymedia) but still would like to see a real alternative to pymedia before i use that.

Comment: what functionality do you need? you could probably get most of the functionality with a command line tool like ffmpeg

Comment: @UkuLoskit yes i'm trying to use pyffmpeg right now

Comment: ok, report the results back here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what "media" are you interested in but you can try:
http://www.pyglet.org/

or:
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow

Answer (score 2):

PyAV is actively developed and binds to ffmpeg/libav. It uses cython as the interface language. http://github.com/mikeboers/PyAV